# Bad UX if a red flag deletes a post in review

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, spam, offensive

If:

1. you have a spam, rude, or abusive post in the first-posts or late-answers queue;
2. you flag it thusly;
3. this flag is the one to bring the post over the deletion threshold (possibly also: another simultaneous flag does the same thing);

this causes the post to be replaced by *question/answer not found* and leaves you with the following situation:

[image: Screenshot of UI]

This is somewhat bewildering since the only thing you can do is <kbd>I’m done</kbd> (which is appropriate since there is literally nothing left that you can possibly do) or <kbd>Skip</kbd> but the post is not shown anymore. This applies even more if the post in question was an answer, where the question is being put into focus.

In Stack Exchange’s UI you are always given all relevant information (or access to it), except here. For example, you cannot tell from this situation whether you accidentally did something wrong or not. If you were briefly distracted after flagging or had to cope with a long loading time, you may not remember what was going on anymore (helped by the fact that flagging most spam is a no-brainer).

To avoid this bad user experience, I suggest that in such a situation either:

- the review is automatically finished (as if you had selected *I’m done*),
- *question/answer not found* is replaced by a more instructive and bigger text, such as

  > Post has been deleted via <spam/rude or abusive> flags; click I'm Done to continue.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is? You *can* click I'm done and that works, right?

Comment: @rene: Sure, it works, but it’s confusing. See my edit.